# How to set property dynamically in a Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic

I have a Expression Like:

```
Expression<Func<RMSGroup, dynamic>> onlyFields = item => new { item.RMSGroupID , item.UpdatedID};
```

I want to add a property "UpdatedDate" dynamically,like

```
=> new {item.RMSGroupID , item.UpdatedID, item.UpdatedDate}
```

How can I modify the expression?

Comment: how familiar are you with the internals of expression-trees? what you ask can be done, but it isn't trivial, and involves pulling the expression apart, modifying the bit you want, and sticking it back together again (perhaps using a visitor)

Comment: In particular, the trickiest thing about *your specific request*, is that the difference between `new { item.RMSGroupID , item.UpdatedID}` and `new {item.RMSGroupID , item.UpdatedID, item.UpdatedDate}` is **huge**. It actually involves creating a whole new type, including custom constructor, etc. It can be done quite easily for examples where the `new` object is not an anonymous type, using a bespoke `ExpressionVisitor` subclass (overriding `VisitNew` and/or `VisitMemberBinding`)

Comment: Thank you, Finally I found another way to do it. I create sql myself.